# Free responsive Carousal - JQuery-CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, carousel

I have the requirement to show vertical and Horizontal Carousal on same web page.

- It need to be responsive
- Need to be vertical or Horizontal
- Open source or free

I tried few of jquery and some of them are not responsive or does not support vertical.

which could be the best option here?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be scared of jQuery. It looks daunting at first but if it's well explained, as in the links below, it's really quite a straightforward task to set up a carousel open-source, fast, and free.

In the tutorials listed below, you'll be able to experiment without losing all patience, so that modifying the script for vertical instead of horizontal scrolling should be easy to accomplish in a half-hour or so.

I too tried to find ready-made scripts which nearly did what I wanted but ready-made carousels are often well-nigh impossible for beginners to tweak to their liking. 
These two you can follow in around 30 minutes, including parameter-tweaking. Then you'll realise building your own is far superior to spending the same amount of time hunting for ready-made scripts...

http://paulmason.name/item/simple-jquery-carousel-slider-tutorial

http://web.enavu.com/tutorials/making-an-infinite-jquery-carousel/

And if you want to be totally sure, for around $5 for a used copy, this book is unbeatable - upbeat style, comprehensive subject treatment:

[http://www.amazon.com/jQuery-Novice-Ninja-Earle-Castledine/dp/0980576857](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0980576857)?